# Compiling Google Mock for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, clang++, googlemock

I am trying to compile Google Mock from sources for iOS. I want to compile it as an archive so that multiple iOS projects can use it.

I am using [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) to build this module (the existing build system uses CMake to build Google Mock as dylibs, so it’s easier if I could use the same method). I had to add the following in [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) to build it as an archive.

`set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)`

The archives are created, but the problem is some of the tests (in gtest_build_tests) are failing.

---

```
The following tests FAILED:
 22 - gtest-filepath_test (SEGFAULT)
 51 - gtest_filter_unittest (Failed)
 54 - gtest_output_test (Failed)
 58 - gtest_xml_outfiles_test (Failed)
 59 - gtest_xml_output_unittest (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

---

How can I built Google Mock as an archive for iOS?

Also I have to manage the build process from the terminal without using an [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) or xcodebuild command.